# How do I make this off canvas menu permanently display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a off canvas navigation bar I found from a template and by default it is set to hide. I want it so that it completely takes the left side of the screen and no matter where the user scroll it will always "be there".

Can someone help me achieve this? Also any way I can make this mobile friendly by possibly making it collapse for smaller screens?

The "menu" button isn't appearing correctly but it is the long grey bar across the slideshow. I have a feeling it is in the css, so I made a comment as to where the css for the navbar begins.

https://jsfiddle.net/nv7rsgpg/9/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Stylish Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<style>


/* Side Menu */

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #222;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 55px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
    left: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.toggle {
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}


.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh;
  }

.vcenter {
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.v-center {
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:40%;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    left:15%;
}    

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#top"  onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Start Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#top" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#services" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <header>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/cats" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/abstract" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/transportation" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>


    <!-- About -->
    <section id="about" class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Stylish Portfolio is the perfect theme for your next project!</h2>
                    <p class="lead">This theme features some wonderful photography courtesy of <a target="_blank" href="http://join.deathtothestockphoto.com/">Death to the Stock Photo</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Services -->
    <!-- The circle icons use Font Awesome's stacked icon classes. For more information, visit http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
    <section id="services" class="services bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <h2>Our Services</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-compass fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Callout -->
    <aside class="callout">
        <div class="text-vertical-center">
            <h1>Vertically Centered Text</h1>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Portfolio -->
    <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h2>Our Work</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-1.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-2.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-3.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-4.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">View More Items</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Call to Action -->
    <aside class="call-to-action bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h3>The buttons below are impossible to resist.</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-light">Click Me!</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark">Look at Me!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Map -->
    <section id="contact" class="map">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        <br />
        <small>
            <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
        </small>
        </iframe>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h4><strong>Start Bootstrap</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <p>3481 Melrose Place<br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> (123) 456-7890</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>  <a href="mailto:name@example.com">name@example.com</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script>
    // Closes the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#myCarousel])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the active class to the sidebar-wrapper

```
<nav id="sidebar-wrapper" class="active">
```

and since you don't want to hide it ever, you can **remove the menu-toggle link**

```
<!-- REMOVE this -->
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

And since the menu is always on, you need to move your body so that it is not covered up. For that you do this

```
body {
   padding-left: 250px;
}
```

Note that because you are using a non-fluid container, this would cause the content to overflow if the screen / window is not large enough. You could work around this a bit by replacing all the containers with container-fluid, but your images are going to look stretched.

The right way would be to modify your responsive wrap points in your Bootstrap less files to account for the menu. But looking at the menu width being hardcoded, I doubt you are targeting smaller screens.

---

Fiddle with container - https://jsfiddle.net/9n8dtr5o/show

Fiddle with container-fluid - https://jsfiddle.net/z9Lknqn7/show

Comment: How do I make it so that it isn't covering any of the site content?

Comment: Updated answer! Remove the /show from the fiddle for the code, if you need it.

Comment: Thanks, one last question, but is there some way to either minimize the navbar for smaller screens or even do something like this where it collapses to the top? http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu/

If it requires a lot of work I can create another question for you.

Comment: You could actually - you'd get more folks looking at it. To get you started, I think you could just add the media query `@media (min-width: 768px) {` around the body to get rid of the extra padding on small screens. Class hidden-xs would hide the components you don't need on smaller screens (visible-xs would show them). Cheers!